# CSS: Partly transparent images in a grid showing the neighboring images behind them, how do I get them to hide completely outside of their own div?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I have this grid with 2 rows and 4 images in each row. I'm trying to make an effect where they start off zoomed in and a little dark (for which I set the background to black and the opacity to 0.7), and when you hover over them they zoom out and become fully opaque.

I have the effect working for the most part, the only problem I'm having is that when the opacity is initially set to 0.7, all the images show the hidden overflow of the images around them.

Here's what I've implemented so far:

```css
#gallery {
    height: 600px;
}

.pictures {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(1.15);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #000;
  background: url('https://pixabay.com/get/ea30b70c2cf1073ed1534705fb094f91e374e3d018ac104496f3c57ba3efb1b0/superb-thread-3563456_1920.jpg');
}

.img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<section id="gallery">
    <div class="pictures">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img img1"></div>
            <div class="img img2"></div>
            <div class="img img3"></div>
            <div class="img img4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img img5"></div>
            <div class="img img6"></div>
            <div class="img img7"></div>
            <div class="img img8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mazink2/h81xf6a2/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply consider an additionnal container with `overflow:hidden`:

```css
#gallery {
    height: 600px;
}

.pictures {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.row > div {
 overflow:hidden;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(1.15);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #000;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069');
}

.img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069');
}
```

```html
<section id="gallery">
        <div class="pictures">
            <div class="row">
                <div><div class="img img1"></div></div>
                <div><div class="img img2"></div></div>
                <div><div class="img img3"></div></div>
                <div><div class="img img4"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div><div class="img img5"></div></div>
                <div><div class="img img6"></div></div>
                <div><div class="img img7"></div></div>
                <div><div class="img img8"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: @MazinAbdulKarim by adding extra container the scale will be hidden them so the elements are no more sibling but each one has it's own container, this container hide the overflow and these container are your new grid items